# Metric-based Auto scaling policies in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have defined the following policies on t2.micro instance:

Take action A whenever {maximum} of CPU Utilization is >= 80% for at least 2 consecutive period(s) of 1 minute.

Take action B whenever {Minimum} of CPU Utilization is <= 20% for at least 2 consecutive period(s) of 1 minute.

Is my interpretation is wrong that: if the min (max) of CPU drops below (goes beyond) 20 (80) for 2 minutes, these rules have to be activated?

Because my collected stats show for example the Max of cpu has reached 90% twice in two consecutive period of 1 minute, but I got No Alarm!

Cheers

Comment: You're correct these settings mean that if your CPU is 80% for more than 2 min, the alarm will be set in ALARM mode. A couple of follow up questions : did you enable detailed monitoring on your instance to get the 1 min granularity ?  (beware : extra costs will apply).  Did you wait a bit more ? (it might take some time to trigger)

Comment: The answer for both of your questions is Yes. Look, this is not always the case, sometimes I got the alarm. But my problem is its unpredictable behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my interpretation is not correct! The policy works based on the Average of the metric for every minute! It means the first policy will be triggered if the AVERAGE of stat Datapoints within a minute is >= 80% for two consecutive periods of 1 minute. The reason is simple: Cloudwatch does not consider stat datapoints less than 1 Min granularity. So if I go for 5 Minutes period, Max and Min show the correct behavior.